# How to build .deb package for a single kernel module?

Tags: kernel, packaging

Is there any helper which can build a .deb package for particular kernel modules from mainstream kernel?

Currently I build a kernel and manually create packagename/DEBIAN/control file, which is quite time consuming

To clarify: I have bunch of embedded devices with particular kernel version installed from deb package. For some reason this devices needs additional modules, which was not shipped. I know how to build kernel manually and know how to build a .deb package for the module. What I am looking for is a deb helper like dh_* for kernel modules.

Comment: It might be easier using DKMS like nVidia and some others do. I used to do that with a Python script that needed to he compiled for grub to call. Using DKMS was fairly straight forward and you don't have to pre-compile for every kernel version. Code is compiled in real time during kernel installation with `apt` or `dpkg`.

Comment: You are most assured doing this in the most difficult way possible. If you are compiling and packaging a kernel, include the module you wish. If not, you know you can compile and install a single module with make sudo make modules_ install ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744087/how-to-recompile-just-a-single-kernel-module

Comment: I would like to share modules for the precompiled kernels

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found old tool, which doing something close to what I want

https://wiki.debian.org/ModuleAssistant

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect answer either, but you can build the whole kernel as a .deb package with `make deb-pkg`

The .deb packages created are reflashing the whole kernel, but I found it to be the simplest/fastest way.